# The black, the white and the red marble(s)

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

I am very confused about the two sentences I am going to make up.

(1) The black, the white and the red marble(s) on the desk are mine.

Please note that in my next example, assume that there are several marbles in each color.

(2) A black, a white and a red marble is or are to be removed from the box.

In (1), do I need to pluralize the word "marble"?

In (2), which verb works better "is" or "are"?

Answer (score 1):

(1) You are using 'the' to specify what marble you are referring to. So you have to use plural if there is at least more than one of each color. Like if there are 2 black but just one of each other color than you need to use 'marbles'.

(2) You are using 'a' this time so you do not refer to specific ones but in general. You are counting them. A marble of each color should be removed. I would say 'is' feels more natural. But when I remember correctly you can also say/use 'are'.